# Session lost window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, session

I'm trying to redirect the user to another page width:

```
window.location.href = "url here" //relative link
```

but when I do, it clears my `sessvars.keyPageArray` variable. Anyone know how to keep a session variable after a redirect?

This is the sessvars library that I am using:
http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

UPDATE: I used google chrome debugger and my script actually does work. For some crazy reason it only works if I'm monitoring it variable by variable but not when I simply run it normally without the debugger on? Why is that happening?

Comment: I posted the libary in the OP. I also have an update. Something really weird is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because you named a variable `sessvars` doesn't make it so. Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage), [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) or cookies depending on your need.

All javascript context is unloaded and lost when the browser navigates to another page.

Example using `localStorage`:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem( "session", JSON.stringify( window.sessvars) );
};

window.onload = function() {
    window.sessvars = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( "session") || "{}" );;
};
```

Comment: I'm using the sessvars library though. I thought that allows you to create session variables without cookies? Here is a link:

http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Comment: @user1410668 seems extremely hacky and last updated 4 years ago.

Comment: I see. It's just the thing that they are using. I'm only an intern so I'm not even sure I have the ability to just decide that I want to use something else. It seems to be working for some example where they are  keeping track of the score the user got in a bunch of exercises using a sessvars array

Comment: @user1410668 you could review the differences between your code and their working code. It could also depend on the browser and how the page is navigated. This is definitely not something one can rely on for their session data.

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are on the **server side**.

Nothing to do with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't keep data after the page is closed, to open anoher page, or eaven on refresh.
Eventualy you can store data in cookie.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing causing the problem is when in server /phptmp directory does not exist or does not have writing permissions.